# In nifi using attributes for storing json path expression does any performance imapct for json to json conversion?

Tags: apache-nifi

In nifi suppose a json having 50 keys is there and I want to fetch 15 values from that by using EvaluateJsonPath does it includes any performance impact, Is it a good practice as I know we can use Jolt transformation,but Using JsonpathEvaluator and ReplaceText is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EvaluateJSONPath` with 15 path expressions (or fewer if you can use patterns) is most likely the best option here.

Comment: In this context, a pattern would be a single JSON Path expression which matched and could capture multiple keys. So rather than a unique expression for `$.some_array[0]` and `$.some_array[1]`, you could have a single expression for `$.some_array[0:1]` to capture both elements or `$.some_array[*]` for all elements of that array. See [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/) and [JSONPath Expressions](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) for more details.

Comment: I have asked another question explaining my use case can you able to answer,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303981/in-nifi-usgae-of-evaluate-jsonpath-processor-will-it-affect-performance-impact-b